# Display Text on Hover Items CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, hover

I am trying to display a text ("innerText") in textInfo-box when I hover the button ("cupcake" or "cheesecake" ). Has anybody an idea how to solve it? I guess only CSS won't make it, so some Javascript will be needed?

So to be a bit clearer. When I hover hover "cupcake" the text "Ice cream fruitcake cotton candy." is supposed to appear in the box below the buttons. And when hover "cheesecake" the text "Chocolate sweet roll chupa chups bonbon macaroon." is supposed to appear.

At the end it should work like this:

[image]

I am happy for any help! Thx.

```css
.textInfo {
  border: solid 1px lightblue;
}

.textInfo:hover {
  background-color: #e8a4c9;
  color: #fff;
}

#pastries:hover + #textInfo .innerText-cupCake {
  display: block;
}

#pastries:hover + #textInfo .innerText-cheeseCake {
  display: block;
}

.innerText-cupCake {
  display: none;
}

.innerText-cheeseCake {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: #e8a4c9;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box pastries" id="pastries">
     <div class="box item cupcake">Cupcake</div>
     <div class="box item cheesecake">Cheesecake</div>
   </div>
   <div class="box textInfo" id="textInfo">
     <h2>Please, select a category first!</h2>
     <div class="innerText-cupCake">
        <p>Ice cream fruitcake cotton candy.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="innerText-cheeseCake">
        <p>Chocolate sweet roll chupa chups bonbon macaroon.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please use this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_hover_tabs.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseleave` event listener for this.
Notice that we added `data-index` and `data-target` respectively for the element that we want to show based on hovering specific element

```js
var pastries = document.getElementById('pastries');

// this handler will be executed every time the cursor is moved over a different list item
  pastries.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
   var dataTarget = event.target.getAttribute('data-target')
  textInfo.querySelector('[data-index="'+ dataTarget +'"]').style.display='block';
  
  }, false);
//for mouseleave, we need to iterate each `#pastries` child element
  var pastriesChildren = document.querySelectorAll('#pastries>.box.item');
  pastriesChildren.forEach(function(pastry){
      pastry.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {    
        var dataTarget = event.target.getAttribute('data-target')
        textInfo.querySelector('[data-index="'+ dataTarget +'"]').style.display='none';

      }, false);
  })
```

```css
.textInfo {
  border: solid 1px lightblue;
}

.textInfo:hover {
  background-color: #e8a4c9;
  color: #fff;
}



.innerText-cupCake {
  display: none;
}

.innerText-cheeseCake {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: #e8a4c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box pastries" id="pastries">
     <div data-target="1" id="cupcake" class="box item cupcake">Cupcake</div>
     <div data-target="2" id="cheesecake" class="box item cheesecake">Cheesecake</div>
   </div>
   <div class="box textInfo" id="textInfo">
     <h2>Please, select a category first!</h2>
     <div data-index="1" class="innerText-cupCake">
        <p>Ice cream fruitcake cotton candy.</p>
     </div>
     <div data-index="2" class="innerText-cheeseCake">
        <p>Chocolate sweet roll chupa chups bonbon macaroon.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thanks a lot.